# How do I get the row (and its index) in an html table from a button click inside a cell in that row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

The question is in the subject line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("yourtableselector td").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents("tr").get(0).rowIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go back up through the DOM until you find the <tr> element.

```
function onclick_handler( event ) {
    var element = event.target;
    while( element.tagName != 'TR' && element.parentNode ) {
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return element.rowIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="alert(this.parentNode.rowIndex);"
```

Unless you have a tbody type tag, then use parentNode twice. Or in jquery:

```
onclick="alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('rowIndex'));"
```